# SPF record setup for Gmail [not send emails to SPAM]

Tags: email, gmail, spf, email-spam

I'm new in administrative tasks :(. 
I try to setup my SPF record corectly.
Current SPF record is 
mydomain.com.au TXT **v=spf1 ip4:198.12.83.12 ~all**

http://www.kitterman.com/ SPF validator got me this

```
SPF record lookup and validation for: mydomain.com.au

SPF records are published in DNS as TXT records.

The TXT records found for your domain are:
v=spf1 198.12.83.12 ~all 

Checking to see if there is a valid SPF record. 

Found v=spf1 record for eliquissurvey.com.au: 
v=spf1 ip4:198.12.83.12 ~all 

evaluating...
Results - PermError SPF Permanent Error: Missing IP4: 198.12.83.12
```

This is headers for Gmail letter i have received in SPAM folder.

```
Delivered-To: mymail@gmail.com
Received: by 10.25.207.137 with SMTP id f131csp3236165lfg;
        Thu, 26 Feb 2015 02:04:15 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.229.70.201 with SMTP id e9mr16802785qcj.6.1424945052932;
        Thu, 26 Feb 2015 02:04:12 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <admin@mydomain.com.au>
Received: from electron.atomiclayer.com (electron.atomiclayer.com. [198.12.83.12])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id 63si211012qhy.111.2015.02.26.02.04.12
        for <mymail@gmail.com>;
        Thu, 26 Feb 2015 02:04:12 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning admin@mydomain.com.au does not designate 198.12.83.12 as permitted sender) client-ip=198.12.83.12;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning admin@mydomain.com.au does not designate 198.12.83.12 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=admin@mydomain.com.au
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; q=dns; c=nofws; s=default; d=mydomain.com.au; b=clMHsk8kJHFNxNRTXc4pWaSgSVFuJJkddQykcHqOK48ydH4uQlqYohK9cYEYRy+o04IakSYYR7zxVpIKQXIjXPpg/kNYeZKga43obbSHYPagXLVB9v+SWbHf6yiSljmE; h=Received:MIME-Version:From:To:Date:Subject:Content-Type:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Message-ID;
Received: from ELECTRON ([127.0.0.1]) by electron.atomiclayer.com with MailEnable ESMTP; Thu, 26 Feb 2015 10:03:11 -0800
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: admin@mydomain.com.au
To: mymail@gmail.com
Date: 26 Feb 2015 10:03:11 -0800
Subject: Reminder for My Questionnaire - Follow
 up for your participation
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Message-ID: <451B2A87E2FC4553A76C21B096788B9C.MAI@electron.atomiclayer.com>
```

Looks like Gmail is not permit **198.12.83.12** as permitted sender? Why?
May be there are black lists, spam filters or something i should care about when send email to Gmail?

Comment: I have similar problems and from what I can see so far, gmail is pretty braindead on SPF and will fail you hard if there is the slightest error. So take that missing IP error seriously, fix it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, syntax is very simple :

```
v=spf1 ip4:1.2.3.4 ip4:1.2.3.4 ~all
```

it also support `mx` , `a` , `include:domain.com`.